# How can I see the upcoming calender event in the always on display?

Tags: calendar, samsung-galaxy-s-8

I have a Galaxy 8 phone that I can customise the content of always on display in some limited way. I could not find any option to add the upcoming calender event to it. Is there any way to do that?

Comment: Did you choose [display calendar](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/58140/customize-always-display-samsung-galaxy-s7/) option ?

Comment: @beeshyams yes, I did.

Answer (score 1):

Go to settings. Then Lock screen and Security. Scroll down to Lock Screen and Always on Display. Select Information and FaceWidgets. Then select FaceWidgets. From there you can select "Today's Schedule" as a screen on Always on Display. (I have the Note 8, but I would imagine you'd do something similar or the same thing.)

Comment: There is no "Information and FaceWidgets".